# Trimmer pot to fixed resistor conversion

Tags: resistors, voltage-divider, potentiometer

Sorry for the simplicity of this question but I've been struggling on this circuit for a while.

In the schematic link below you'll see a trimmer pot and I simply want to replace it with one/two fixed resistors.

I'm under the impression it will be two resistor to form a voltage divider, but still struggling to achieve this.

Following the schematic that states the 10k pot should be tuned to ~7.8k how would the circuit be rewritten to include fixed resistors?

http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Kits/UhOh-v11_corrected.pdf

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsVwm2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the bottom part of the pot is 7.8K then the top should be 10K-7.8K = 2.2K.

For the feedback voltage to equal the reference (2.495V), the voltage at the
top of the divider would have to be (10/7.8)*2.495V = 3.20V.

Comment: Thank you very much. Am I right in assuming that if I wish to change the threshold from 3.2V to ~3.5V the resistors change from 2.2k and 7.8k to 2.85k and 7.15k respectively (approximate values)? (I imagine the third 330 resistor remains the same)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You can alter the total 10K a bit to get the ratio correct with common resistor values. For example, ratio is 2.85:7.15 so you could use 3K:7.5K -> 3.49V.